# Android Studio - Tooltips ¿Cómo hago para que los tooltip desaparezcan?

Tags: android, android-studio, tooltip

**Descripción**

Tengo una app la cual contiene dos **Text Views** en el centro de la pantalla. El primero tiene mi nombre (Tomás). El segundo tiene mi apellido. Estos txt view son clickeables y, al hacerlo, aparecerá un **Tooltip** el cual mostrará mi segundo nombre o apellido según lo clikeado.

**Problema:**

El problema es que al tocar ambos, los tooltips se superpondrán entre sí.

**Me gustaría que al tocar un texto, un tooltip desaparezca para que solo se pueda ver el que se seleccionó (Es decir, que nunca puedan haber dos tooltips en pantalla).**

**Adjunto el código JAVA de mis tooltips**

```
//TXT NOMBRE EVENT LISTENER
    txt_nombre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView txt = (TextView) v;
            final Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip.Builder(txt)
                    .setText("Ariel")
                    .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
                    .setGravity(Gravity.TOP)
                    .setCornerRadius(8f)
                    .setDismissOnClick(true)
                    .setArrowHeight(18f)
                    .show();

            p.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tooltip.dismiss();
                }
            },3000);
        }
    });
```

**Dependencia:**

```
implementation 'com.github.vihtarb:tooltip:0.1.9'
```

**Gracias por leer!!**

Comment: Hola @TomasM que dependencia estas usando? depende de esta información para proporcionar una solución

Comment: Hola de nuevo Jorge. Que usuario increíble. Siempre participando! La dependencia es: implementation 'com.github.vihtarb:tooltip:0.1.9'

Comment: Puedes crear un array de ToolTips o simplemente otra instancia y verificas si existe la otra para llamar .dismiss() y que este deje de aparecer@TomasM , saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cancelar individualmente cada ToolTip tienes que definir dos instancias diferentes uno para el nombre y otro para el apellido,

```
private Tooltip tooltipNombre = null;
private Tooltip tooltipApellido = null;
```

de esta forma puedes verificar si existe el `tooltipApellido` llamar `dismiss()` para cancelarlo, realizarías lo mismo para el caso de tooltipApellido verificas si existe el `tooltipNombre` y llamas `dismiss()` para cerrarlo  :

```
   txt_nombre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //*Verifica si existe tooltipApellido, lo cancela!
            if (tooltipApellido!=null){
                tooltipApellido.dismiss();
            }
            TextView txt = (TextView) v;
              tooltipNombre = new Tooltip.Builder(getContext(), txt)
                    .setText("Nombre")
                    .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
                    .setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
                    .setCornerRadius(8f)
                    .setDismissOnClick(true)
                    .setArrowHeight(18f)
                    .show();

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tooltipNombre.dismiss();
                }
            },3000);
        }
    });

    txt_apellido.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //*Verifica si existe tooltipNombre, lo cancela!
            if (tooltipNombre!=null){
                tooltipNombre.dismiss();
            }
            TextView txt = (TextView) v;
            tooltipApellido = new Tooltip.Builder(getContext(), txt)
                    .setText("Apellido")
                    .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
                    .setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
                    .setCornerRadius(8f)
                    .setDismissOnClick(true)
                    .setArrowHeight(18f)
                    .show();

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tooltipApellido.dismiss();
                }
            },3000);
        }
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que estas usando vihtarb:tooltip, en ese caso esto deberia solucionar tu problema.

```
Tooltip tooltipNombre;
Tooltip tooltipApellido;

private void initTooltips(){
   tooltipNombre = new Tooltip.Builder(txt_nombre)
                .setText("Ariel")
                .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
                .setGravity(Gravity.TOP)
                .setCornerRadius(8f)
                .setDismissOnClick(true)
                .setArrowHeight(18f)
                .build();//En lugar de usar show podes usar build() para que quede inicializado
   tooltipNombre = new Tooltip.Builder(txt_apellido)
                .setText("Ariel")
                .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
                .setGravity(Gravity.TOP)
                .setCornerRadius(8f)
                .setDismissOnClick(true)
                .setArrowHeight(18f)
                .build();
}

txt_nombre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (tooltipApellido.isShowing()) {
            tooltipApellido.dismiss();
        }
        tooltipNombre.show();
        p.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tooltipNombre.dismiss();
            }
        },3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias de nuevo Erick. El problema es: ¿Como inicio un Tooltip sin usar el .show? En el código que adjuntas, hay dos tooltips en el método "Init Tooltips" pero ninguno termina con un cierre de instrucción (" ; "). El problema que estoy teniendo es que no puedo iniciar un tooltip sin que tengan el .show. En resumen, quiero mantener mis tooltips iniciados y mostrarlos cuando se me de la gana, pero Android Studio no me lo permite porque me hace cerrar SI O SI los tooltip con un punto y coma. Situación distinta a la que me mostraste en el ejemplo

Comment: perdon, me olvide una linea de codigo. Ahi edito la respuesta.